# How to send intents into gameView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to have what the user types in the textEdits in the StartScreen Activity to show up in my MainActivity.

First I created my 2 intents for the 2 users.

```
String playerOneContent = playerOneEditText.getText().toString();
String playerTwoContent = playerTwoEditText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, GameView.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME", playerOneContent);
intent.putExtra("NAME2", playerTwoContent);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in my `GameView` I have the following code:

```
public class GameView extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Context context;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    canvas.drawText("NAME",50, 50, paint);
    }
}
```

**How would I get the intents from the `StartScreen` and use it in the `GameView`?**

This is the code I had in my `Main Activity` originally:

```
TextView playerOneTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerOneTextView);
TextView playerTwoTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.playerTwoTextView);

playerOneTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME"));
playerTwoTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME2"));
```

Comment: Hello user11686570 and welcome to StackOverflow. May I ask, **what exactly is your question**? It looks like you already are getting the intents from `StartScreen` through `getIntent()` so is there a certain problem that you are running into or some unexpected behavior?

If so, would you be able to post an image or log of the errors or the expected behavior and resulting behavior?

Comment: Yes, if I am using the GameView I don't think I can have anything in the MainActivity without having an error. So I tried to use getIntent in the GameView but it doesn't let me because GameView is not an activity, just a class that extends to MainActivity. Also, in the MainActivity when I had setText, you can't do that for GameView, that's why I used canvas.

Comment: I think what you may have to do is create a constructor for `GameView` and then pass in the `context`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **intents don't work in Android without extending the Activity class.**

Therefore, what you can do is create an object of the `MainActivity` class in your `GameView` class and get the value of the variables.

So something like this in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public String playerOneContent;
public String playerTwoContent;

@Override
public void onCreate...... //blah blah blah

public void functionWhereYouSetValueofStrings(){
    playerOneContent = playerOneEditText.getText().toString();
    playerTwoContent = playerTwoEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

Now, in the `GameView.java` class do the following to get the values:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
playerOneTextView.setText(ma.playerOneContent);
playerTwoTextView.setText(ma.playerTwoContent);
```

It's using the Object to refer to the `public` fields that you have in `MainActivity.java`. I believe that this should answer your question, and help you.

If not, then just make a comment with the problem below.

Comment: Did you mean to put that first block of code in StartScreen? Because the editTexts are in the StartScreen activity. Otherwise playerOneEditText and playerTwoEditText show up as errors.

Comment: Yes. Wherever you are getting the text for the two `EditTexts`, have the 2 `String` variables. Then in `GameView` have the other section of code.

Comment: MainActivity is the one with the TextViews, not GameView. That's why I used canvas.drawText.

Comment: Ok. So get the text from `MainActivity` and set the variables to those values and then use the `.` operator to refer to them in the `GameView`. Is there a problem?